# How to reconfigure user accounts correctly while deploying meteor app using mup

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, web-deployment, facebook-authentication, meteor-accounts

I am having Facebook and Google user accounts in my meteor app. I did setup them using accounts-ui package using the nice default UI of it. But I removed the default UI and added some custom buttons. How to reconfigure the private and public keys when deploying now? I am using [mup](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) to deploy.

Comment: `settings.json` + read the MUP docs it has all the information about it

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was something like settings.json and settings.production.json

You make mup use the latter one.

Edit: or it was settings.development.json and settings.json, the latter one is the default?

Answer (score 0):

> You could use a production or development settings file for deploying
>   your apps:
>
> http://themeteorchef.com/snippets/making-use-of-settings-json/

```
meteor deploy example.meteor.com --settings setting-production.json
```

setting-production.json =>

```
{
    "kadira": {
                  "appId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                  "appSecret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
              },
    "reCaptcha": {
        "secretKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "public": {
        "reCaptcha": {
            "siteKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXN"
        }
    }
}
```